# Logistic regression with categorical independent variables and binomial count dependent variables

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, python, statsmodels

The problem is from football. I have the full time goals(FTG), and shots on target minus goals(FST), as the dependent variables (integers). Team names, opponent team names (strings) and home field indicator (=1 if at home; =0 if away) are independent variables. I want to analyse the probability of a shot on target actually becomes a goal conditional on the independent variables.

```
    formula2='FTG+FST~Team+Opponent+Home'
    mod2 = smf.glm(formula2, data=df, family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit()
```

It gives

```
    ValueError: The first guess on the deviance function returned a nan.  This could be a boundary  problem and should be reported.
```

I would like to ask how to implement this logistic regression. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's not clear if you are asking us for how to code this or how to "perform logistic regression" generally (i.e. the steps involved in carrying out the analysis).  Can you clarify?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I would like to know how to code it.

Comment: Then I'm going to vote to close this and have it migrated to stack overflow.  Coding questions are off-topic for this board.  See the forum tour/rules here:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour.

Comment: Actually I am not sure the error is from a statistic problem or a coding problem...

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the dependent variable of your logistic regression is not coded as 0/1, which I think will cause problems with the statsmodels GLM routines.

Also, I don't think you want the left side of the equation (ahead of the `~`) to be the sum of two variables.  If you really want the arithmetic sum, you could use this:

`I(FTG+FST) ~ Team+Opponent+Home`

but I don't think that's what you actually want.

If you have a count of attempts per player, and also the number of successes, you could use Poisson regression, with number of attempts as the exposure (or just include log(attempts) as a covariate).

Or, if you have shot-level data, instead of player-level data, you could use logistic regression, but then you might want to think about the correlation among records for the same player.

Comment: FTG+FST used is due to the misunderstanding of syntax of GLM with binomial family in statsmodels. I use ratio instead.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you want to analyse proba of scoring a goal you should probably analyse the ratio "goals / attempts" rather than attempts minus goals. As the resulting variable will take a range of values between 0 and 1 (not only 0 or 1), you might consider other types of regression (depending on the distribution of your dependent variable), such as Beta regression. Regarding the independent variables, not sure what you want to do with "team names" - How is it coded? The IVs have to be numerical.

Comment: Yes I used ratio instead. (Team) is a categorical variable

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the data to use the ratio of goal / shot (SUCCESS) as the dependent variable.

```
    df['SUCCESS']=df['FTG']/df['ST']
    formula2='SUCCESS~Home+Team+Opponent'
    mod2 = smf.glm(formula2, data=df[df['SUCCESS'].notnull()], family=sm.families.Binomial()).fit()
```

The error is due to own goals so sometimes df['FTG']/df['ST']>1.